# How to access current_user with devise-token_authenticatable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, graphql, react-apollo, devise-token-auth

I’m working on a small project that is using `devise` and `devise-token_authenticatable` in a `Rails/GraphQL/Apollo/React` setup. Project is setup using `webpacker`, so the front and back ends are both served from the same domain. Sign-in, register, log-out are all handle by the front end (React). I also need to point out this is not an API only app.

It seems, server is not setting the `current_user` or the proper cookie and I’m getting a network error.

Heroku logs shows the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `authentication_token' for #<User:0x000055ca6c0e4c50>)
```

Is that mean it’s trying ‘authentication_token’ method on a nil class?

At the same time it’s showing this error in the console:

```
Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (I have no idea what this is)
```

In my login component’s sign-in mutation, I’m storing the authentication_token of the user in local storage after a successful login and in my Apollo setup I’m retrieving it from storage and attaching it to each request. But Chrome dev tool’s network tab shows I’m not getting the cookie set by devise after a signin in the response header. I’m pretty new to all of this so not sure this is the problem or something else. PS: I’m not using Devise sessions since sign-in is handle in the from end. I have `devise_for: users, skip: :sessions` in my routes.

**Code snippets:**

[Apollo Provide](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/BhatiyaJayasuriya/bL87y8/apollo-provider)

[Component UserInfo](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/BhatiyaJayasuriya/qnB6kL/user-info)

[SignIn mutation](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/BhatiyaJayasuriya/Ebojgj/sign-in-mutation)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE: issue was fixed:** (also see my answer below for additional info)

Issue was fixed by adding `current_user` private method in `application_controller.rb`.

Here's the code...

```
def current_user
 token = request.headers["Authorization"].to_s
 User.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_token: token)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Marko Kacanski was right I should have elaborate on my findings & how I fixed it. :-(

I was wrong to assume that the `current_user` is automatically sent by the gem `devise-token_authenticatable` when it detects a `authentication_token` in the header. At least the way I have setup my project, I wasn't getting the `current_user` as expected, instead I get a nil object.

So... I created a `current_user` private method in `application_controller.rb` and, it fixed the issue.

Here's the code...

```
def current_user
 token = request.headers["Authorization"].to_s
 User.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_token: token)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Fixed the issue. It had nothing to do with GraphQl/Apollo code. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could share the solution with the rest of the community?

Comment: Thank you, I was dealing with a similar issue and your solution really helped! :) If you edit your original quesiton, I'll be able to upvote it since it now has a very usefull answer.